# Check membership of custom group in Windows C++

Tags: c++, windows, active-directory

I have a Windows application where I ideally want to give certain functionality to certain levels of system security. This is already in place for admin vs non admin and this was easy enough, but say I had 3 network groups defined like "Security1", "Security2", "Security3", is there a way that I could tell if the current user running the application is a member of one of these groups?

I have looked around but all I can find is for determining the membership of a well-known group as this group has a well-known SID.

So is there any way to do this for custom groups?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but if you can get the user name of the current user (which should be fairly easy if the application isn't a service), you should be able to query with

```
net user <userName> /domain | find "Group"
```

[How to execute a command and get output of command within C++ using POSIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c)
 Describes how to execute a command from C++.

To debug:

```
net user [username] /domain
net user [username]
```

Check which of those is what you're looking for.

Comment: I have tried this on mine and a colleague's account and it is what I need but seems to only list one global group membership on each of us, where I would expect more to be listed. Is there some parameter you need to add to list all? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Hmm, try net user without the /domain. The /domain is if your accounts are network accounts.